# What is the Python UDFs concurrency limit in Redshift Serverless

Tags: amazon-redshift-serverless

In redshift serverless, what is the Python UDF concurrency limit?
How do we identify if limit has been hit during multiple query executions?
How do we identify if the query is queued for execution , due to limit has been crossed?
[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-constraints.html)

> The number of Python UDFs that can run concurrently per cluster is limited to one-fourth of the total concurrency level for the cluster. For example, if the cluster is configured with a concurrency of 15, a maximum of three UDFs can run concurrently. After the limit is reached, UDFs are queued for execution within workload management queues. SQL UDFs don't have a concurrency limit.